# Is there anyway to clear _Int64List in flutter?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, dart, ram

So I have a problem when I open up the PDF in flutter, It increases my ram usage , and when I close the page that contains the PDF file, my ram usage doesn't decrease. I found out by using dart devtools memory, that my memory usage increases because of the _Int64List. So when I open the PDF file, the instance of the _Int64List increases. Is there anyway to clear _Int64List?[image]

Comment: Does [`Int64List.clear()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/clear.html) not do what you want?  Also note that Dart is garbage-collected, so when you close the page that contains the PDF file, you might not notice an immediate decrease in memory usage until the GC runs (which might not be until there's memory pressure).

Comment: I have used that Int64List.clear() but it didn't select the Int64List instance in dart devtools, and about the PDF File that need times to decrease, it doesn't decrease at all. It stays.

Comment: You cannot `clear()` a `Int64List` since its size is fixed. The only way to get rid of it is to ensure there are no reference to the object.

Comment: @julemand101 how to ensure it?

Comment: @Codex Difficult to answer. It would require a look at the code and make an analyze of how your PDF reader are using the `Int64List` objects. Not sure if DevTools has some way to pinpoint the references which keeps a given object alive.

Comment: Do you know how Advance Pdf Viewer using the Int64List? Any recommendation for Pdf Viewer Libraries?

Comment: @Codex Not a Flutter (or front-end in general...) developer so I don't know about PDF render libraries for Flutter. I took a general overview over `advance_pdf_viewer` but could not see anything problematic. Again, it is difficult to ensure you are not keeping a reference to objects generate by the package. You really need the source code of the app.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a garbage collection with the Dart DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I found the solution by changing the package from advance_pdf_viewer to flutter_pdf_view.